# KendoUI grid - turning pagination on / off programmatically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like pagination to show only if I have **more records than my pageSize**.  Is there any way to achieve this affect?

Ideally as data is added/removed on the client the pagination mechanism would show/hide accordingly (again, only displaying if there are more items than the pagesize).

Any ideas/workarounds?

**Update**

The answer provided by j4ro seems to work great once I removed the height setting code.  It was not necessary for me, but your mileage may vary as I didn't test this with a more typical use-case.

```
dataBound: function () {
    if (this.dataSource.totalPages() === 1) {
        this.pager.element.hide();
    }
    else {
        this.pager.element.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this function to your grid on dataBound event:

```
dataBound: function () {
        var gridContent = this.element.find('.k-grid-content');
        if (this.dataSource.totalPages() === 1) {
            gridContent.css('height', gridContent.height() + this.pager.element.innerHeight());
            this.pager.element.hide();
        }
        else {
            this.pager.element.show();
            gridContent.css('height', gridContent.height() - this.pager.element.innerHeight());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like the right approach but doesn't seem quite right.   Result: Given a page size of 10, if items < 10 the pager is hidden, however the height of the grid is one row tall (or perhaps the height of the pager). When items > 10, only the pager is visible.   I am using knockout-kendo library to perform the binding, not sure if that interferes with this approach...

Comment: Updated my answer - this worked great when i removed the height setting code.  I didn't need it for the way I'm using the grid (with duranda+knockout-kendo). Thanks!